# How to fix HTTP error 407 when using ECB package in R?

Tags: r, curl, fetch-api, ecb, http-status-code-407

I am using currently the package "ecb", which leverages the package "curl" in order to retrieve data from the ECB Data Warehouse website.

The called function is `df <- get_data("MIR.M.AT.B.L21.A.R.A.2230.EUR.N")`
but I am getting the following error:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
> Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
A few weeks ago the download was successful.